# Category-based Navigation in DXA

Tags: dxa, dxa-1.6, navigation

I am using DXA 1.6 in SDL Web 8. I'm trying to use a Taxonomy to generate the site navigation. As mentioned in DXA's documentation, we can generate navigation using a Category whose name contains [Navigation] instead of SGs (https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v6/GUID-DADB74A6-801B-49A7-95B1-FA3AB05C6CB7).

I did the steps according to the documentation, but it didn't work. This is the structure of `Sitemap [Navigation]`.

[image]

I have created index pages for each Keyword with prefix consisting of 3 numbers and used metadata Schema ***Page Navigation Metadata*** to link to corresponding Keyword. And I checked that both Pages and the Category were published.

Does anyone know the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The DXA Web App has to be configured for Category/Taxonomy-based navigation too; OOTB it uses a so-called *Static Navigation Provider* and for Taxonomy-based Navigation you need the *Dynamic Navigation Provider*.

The *Dynamic Navigation Provider* looks for a **published** Taxonomy with `[Navigation]` in its title and if it doesn't find it, it falls back to SG-based navigation (so you can have different nav types in different Publications).

The Navigation Provider type is configured in `Unity.config` (for DXA.NET) and can also be provided as parameter to `web-install.ps1`.

Comment: If I run the web-install.ps1 without specifying the navigation parameter, the web app will use the static navigation in default? If so, if I want to use the dynamic navigation, I need to add "<type type="INavigationProvider" mapTo="DynamicNavigationProvider">" to Unity.config?

Comment: Correct (2x) :-)